# Follow new window after swing action emulated

Tags: java, swing, reflection

Using reflection, I've managed to invoke the main method of another java application that uses swing to create windows. I've also been able to grab those windows and manipulate them. When I get to a certain point, I loop through the actionListeners of a certain JMenuItem and I call their actionPerformed telling them the button has been pressed. This works exactly as intended, and opens a new window. When this window opens, however, I want to do something similar to it by first getting the window and then the components inside of it.

However, as soon as the event is fired, the window is created and my program is put in a busy loop waiting for the window I want to interact with to close. This is caused by the application I am invoking, and I have no control over this, nor do I have an opportunity to do anything about it.
Here's how I am doing that event firing

`for (ActionListener a : nc.getActionListeners()) {
    a.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(nc, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,null) {});
}`

What I'm thinking is I might want to have another thread that's looking for the window, but I'm not even sure if that will work..

Answer (score 2):

Window has static method

```
public static Window[] getWindows() {
    return getWindows(AppContext.getAppContext());
}
```

Frame has similar one

```
public static Frame[] getFrames()
```

So you can get copy of the created windows (frames) before your click emulation and compare with the new list after click to find the newly created one.

Comment: @Christopher Wirt then you can loop inside arrays of Window/Frames and to get all JCompoents, its value, setting without reflection, use instanceof

Comment: I don't think you guys quite understand my problem. I'm getting windows and frames just fine, it's that the application I'm invoking creates another thread for another window when I fire a button click event, and that forces MY program to wait until the window is closed. IE I can't do anything.. Thanks for trying, I guess..